# .NET 8 Console App DI Error 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory'

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, console-application

I'm trying to add dependency injection to a .NET 8 Console Application following the explanation in this video [How to use Dependency Injection (DI) in C# Console Application with Logging](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLHyeXrt3Jk) but I get the following error:

**"Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory'."**

This is the code of the Program.cs

```
ServiceCollection services = new();

services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Localization");

services.AddSingleton<ILocalizationService, LocalizationService>();
services.AddScoped<IEntityService, EntityService>();

var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

EntityService service = new(provider.GetService<ILocalizationService>());
```

This is the code of the LocalizationService class

```
public class LocalizationService : ILocalizationService
{
public class SharedResource { }

private readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;
public LocalizationService(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
{
    var type = typeof(SharedResource);
    var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName!);
    _localizer = factory.Create("Resource", assemblyName.Name!);
}
public LocalizedString GetKey(string key)
{
    return _localizer[key];
}
}
```

This is the Entity Service class

```
public class EntityService(ILocalizationService localization) : IEntityService
{
   ...
}
```

The error occurs at this line of the Program.cs

```
EntityService service = new(provider.GetService<ILocalizationService>());
```

I tried a lot of solutions found on stack overflow but nothing helped and don't need the logging.

How to fix this error?

Comment: Logging dies not seem to be registered. I didn't watch the Video, but do they obtain their service provider from a HostBuilder?

Comment: Did you forgot to call `services.AddLogging()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.localization.resourcemanagerstringlocalizerfactory.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0#microsoft-extensions-localization-resourcemanagerstringlocalizerfactory-ctor(microsoft-extensions-options-ioptions((microsoft-extensions-localization-localizationoptions))-microsoft-extensions-logging-iloggerfactory)) depends on `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory` which is required for service to be resolved via DI.

You are missing [`LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.AddLogging`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.loggingservicecollectionextensions.addlogging?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) call. For example add [`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/8.0.0) nuget:

```cs
services.AddLogging(lb => lb.AddConsole());
```

If you don't want actual logging then [`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/) is sufficient with the following registration:

```cs
services.AddLogging();
```

Comment: Thanks! now I understand why I got that error. It works by adding the services.AddLogging() and also with the hostbuilder explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-usage

Comment: @ZotNet yes, host builder includes by default a lot of such stuff. See also the [generic hosting doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host?tabs=appbuilder#host-builder-settings)